# When the client socket should be bound in order to receive UDP messages from a server?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-10.04, udpclient

I have seen two examples that illustrate how the client socket can receive messages from server.

Example 1:

server code
http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/sockets/ud_ucase_sv.c.html

client code
http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/sockets/ud_ucase_cl.c.html

The client program creates a socket and binds the socket to an address, so that the server can send its reply.

```
if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &claddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
    errExit("bind"); // snippet from ud_ucase_cl.c
```

Example 2:

server code
http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/sockets/i6d_ucase_sv.c.html

client code
http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/sockets/i6d_ucase_cl.c.html

In example 2, client code doesn't bind its socket with an address.

**Question**:

*Is it necessary for the client code to bind the socket with an address in order to receive message from server?*

*Why in the first example, we have to bind the client socket with an address, why we don't have to in the second example?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the **`socket family`** - first example uses **`AF_UNIX`**, while the second does **`AF_INET6`**. According to [Stevens UNP](http://books.google.com/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA418#v=onepage&q&f=false) you need to explicitly `bind` pathname to Unix client socket so that the server has a pathname to which it can send its reply:

> ... sending a datagram to an unbound Unix domain datagram socket does not implicitly bind a pathname to the socket. Therefore, if we omit this step, the server's call to `recvfrom` ... returns a null pathname ...

This is not required for `INET{4,6}` sockets since they are "auto-bound" to an ephemeral port.

Answer (score 1):

For the client (TCP) or sender (UDP), calling `bind()` is optional; it is a way to specify the interface. Suppose you have two interfaces, which are both routable to your destination:

```
eth0: 10.1.1.100/24
eth1: 10.2.2.100/24

route: 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.2.2.254  # router for eth1
       0.0.0.0     via 10.1.1.254  # general router
```

Now if you just say `connect()` to `12.34.56.78`, you don't know which local interface furnishes the local side of the connection. By calling `bind()` first, you make this specific.

The same is true for UDP traffic: Without `bind()`ing, your `sendto()` will use a random source address and port, but with `bind()` you make the source specific.

Comment: Then why in the second example, we don't have to use bind and still are able to send messages to server?

Comment: You can *always* send messages. You just don't have control over the source interface and port.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not bound AF_INET/AF_INET6 client socket before connecting/sending something, TCP/IP stack will automatically bind it to ephemeral port on outbound address.

Unlike this, UNIX domain sockets (AF_UNIX) do not automatically bind when sending, so you can send messages via SOCK_DGRAM but can't get any replies.